# List in iTextsharp can not be displayed

Tags: c#, list, pdf, itext

I am working with iTextsharp librairies to generate a pdf file. I a m using list.add() to add lines and data. In the beginning it went well ( when i added 10 list items) but when i continued adding a big number a listitems (about 20 items) it throws  me this exception : "Unbalanced begin/end text operators" in the line doc.close();
I am wondering how can I resolve this. Thank you

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Also, which version of iTextSharp are you using?